# How to remove PhysicsBody outline in Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In the game I am working on, several objects have physics bodies used for collision detection. When I run the game on my iPhone, these bodies are indicated by outlining each object with a bright green or blue line. Is there any way I can remove this? Is this only present when testing apps? I am using Swift and iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point you're enabling the showsPhysics property of your SKView. Should look something like this:

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

This property defaults to false, so removing the line of code enabling it will be enough to disable the behavior.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I think the reason I had it on was because I watched a tutorial which added it and didn't know what it was for but assumed it was important.

Comment: @Tommy Glad to hear it helped. And yes, showsPhysics isn't necessary, but can be helpful tool for debugging, which is probably why it was enabled by the author of your tutorial. I suggest taking a look at the class reference for SKView. There are a few more helpful debugging properties that can be enabled.